# Why didn't Castiel smite the vampires in Season 13 episode 21?

Tags: supernatural

In Season 13 Episode 21, the gang goes up against vampires in the alternate world. It's basically up to Sam and Dean to take care of them while Gabriel and Castiel remain in the background.

While Castiel is no longer as powerful as he was in seasons 6-8 (or Seasons 4 and 5 for that matter), we've seen him smite demons this season, so he should be able to smite vampires; but the few times we saw him get near them, he didn't. Why is this?

Comment: Were they especially pretty vampires?  Maybe he was... smitten =P